# Get value from form fields

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get the values from the form fields in **handleSubmit(event)**, however, **new FormData** does not return the values. Is there anything else I need to get the data or am I doing wrong?

```
class Login extends Component {

    constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.target);

    debugger;
    request({
        url: "/login",
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });

    }

    render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>User/E-mail:</label><br />
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
                <br />
                <br />

                <label>Password:</label><br />
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
                <br />
                <br />

                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: I don't think you can just call `JSON.stringify` on a `FormData` object. Does your endpoint actually expect the data in JSON format?

Comment: See [Forms - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) for examples of forms are typically managed in React

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it this way:

```
request({
    url: "/login",
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then(function(response){
    if(response.ok) {
    response.text().then((token) => {
        if(token){
            localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, token)
        }
    })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are relying on the browser a bit much there, i would control those inputs in state,so you dont need to look for the values when you submit:

```
class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password:'',
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange = event =>{
      const { target: { name, value } } = event;
      this.setState({[name]: value})
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { state: { username, password } } = this;
    const data =  { username, password }

    debugger;
    request({
        url: "/login",
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });

  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>User/E-mail:</label><br />
            <input onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" id="username" name="username" />
            <br />
            <br />

            <label>Password:</label><br />
            <input onChange={this.handleChange} type="password" id="password" name="password" />
            <br />
            <br />

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
   }
  }

export default Login;
```

Comment: I tested with your code and it also does not take the value of the fields.
I'm finding it strange that the code I posted in the question was working and now it does not work anymore. Do you have any idea what might be causing this problem?